# function fopen isn't working when i use "a" or "w"

Tags: c, file, fopen

i'm not a english speaker so i'll try my best.

I'm a student and I'm having a problem when i try to manipulate a FILE.

When i put fopen with "a", i was able to create a file in the local main's folder, but after .txt was created, when i try to add something with "a" or "w", the pointer can't load the .txt. When i try with "r", it says that was able to open.

This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *arq;
    arq = fopen("depois.txt", "a");

    int x = 15;

    if(arq == NULL){
        printf("Didn't work.");
    }else{
        printf("Work");
        fprintf(arq,"%d", x);
    }

    

    fclose(arq);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The line `fclose(arq);` will invoke undefined behavior if the file was not successfully opened. You should only call that function if the file was successfully opened. Therefore, I suggest that you move that line into the `else` block.

Comment: Or just exit the program when opening the file fails.

Comment: Although ISO C does not require this, most platforms will set `errno` to provide additional information on why `fopen` failed. Therefore, you may want to change the line `printf("Didn't work.");` to `perror("Didn't work");`, so that you will additionally get a description of the error (e.g. "file not found" or "access denied").

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thank you for the observations and tips, i put fclose into the else block, and figured out, with perror, that the problem is "Permission denied". You just changed my world. I'll try to solve this.